# Where are the data files included in MANIFEST.IN stored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, manifest, packaging

I have this small program do it with Python3.5 with the following structure:

```
awesome_gui/
    app.config
    MANIFEST.in
    setup.py
    awesome_gui/
       __init__.py
       main.py
```

setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name = "awesomegui",
    version = "1.0",
    author = "Me",
    author_email = "me@example.com",
    description = "Awesome GUI",
    packages=['awesome_gui'],
    entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': ['awesomegui=awesome_gui.main'],
    },
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

MANIFEST.in

```
include app.config
```

After execute the following line and create the .deb:

> $ python3 setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb

And unpack with:

> $ sudo dpkg -i deb_dist/python3-awesomegui_1.0-1_all.deb

The code (*.py) is saved in **/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awesome_gui/**. But I do not see where **app.config** is saved.

Does anyone know where the data files that are non-code are stored?

Thank you!

Comment: Please cut down your question to the absolute minimum. I see a lot of unnecessary code and content in your question.

Comment: @JonathanBenn thanks for the advice, I'm new and I'm learning. The fact is that I do not know where the data files are stored after do 'dpkg' of my .deb

Comment: I was looking answers for the same @Ribes. Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes. I have added an answer, see if it can be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because people have asked me how I solved the problem, I describe it below. I did the following with respect to the initial approach:

- I changed the structure of the initial project to this one:

  ```
  awesome_gui/
      MANIFEST.in
      setup.py        
      awesome_gui/
          app.config
          src/
              __init__.py
              main.py
  ```

You can see that the ***app.config*** file has been moved into the ***awesome_gui/*** project folder  and a folder named ***src*** has also been created and the code moved into it.

- **setup.py** file was also edited:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import os
  from setuptools import setup


  setup(
      name = "awesomegui",
      version = "1.0",
      author = "Me",
      author_email = "me@example.com",
      description = "Awesome GUI",
      packages=['awesome_gui',
                'awesome_gui.src',
                ],
      entry_points = {
      'console_scripts': ['awesomegui=awesome_gui.src.main:main'],
      },
      include_package_data=True,
      package_data={"awesome_gui": ['app.config']},
   )
  ```

Added ***src*** folder in ***packages*** and in ***entry_points*** fields. Also added the ***package_data*** field with the non python file.

- By adding a folder level, the **MANIFEST.in** was also modified:

  ```
  include awesome_gui/app.config
  ```

After installing with the commands, with these steps I got the non python files to be in the **/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awesome_gui/** folder.

Comment: I have the same problem, but even after that it doesn't find the file... What path to `app.config` did you put in the code that reads it?

Comment: Okay, I solved this issue by using the path `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'myfile.txt')`.
I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this. Why isn't the directory the file is in, also in the search path?

Answer (score -2):

normally, package data should be in package directory(besides `main.py` for example). 
readme.txt, license, long description as package data in root directory mostly are used in sdist, pypi and won't be installed.